# readarray -t option in bash default behavior?

Tags: arrays, bash

From `man bash` on `readarray`:

> -t
>   Remove any trailing newline from a line read, before it is assigned to an array element.

Is -t default behavior for readarray in bash?

I tested it couple of times with -t and without on a file with newlines
no difference noticed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is indeed a difference:

```
# Newlines are retained as part each array element
$ readarray foo <<EOF
> foo
> bar
> baz
> EOF
$ printf '%s' "${foo[@]}"
foo
bar
baz

# Newlines are stripped
$ readarray -t foo <<EOF
foo
bar
baz
EOF

$ printf '%s' "${foo[@]}"
foobarbaz
```

The format to `printf` does not include a newline, so the first example only prints each element on a separate line because each element itself ends with a newline. In the second example, all three elements are printed on the same line.

Comment: It should be noted that the behavior of `-t` depends on whether the `-d` option is specified. If `-d` is used, then `-t` strips whatever the delimiter supplied is, otherwise it strips newlines. The documentation probably needs to reflect this subtle behavior